# Convert C# code

Tags: c#, ilgenerator

I need to simulate in C# code (with ilGenerator.Emit) the following function

```
public void AssignAttribute(ref ValueHolder output, Assignment assignment) {
    ResultAttribute attribute = null;

    if ( (attribute = output.MultipleResults.Find(delegate(ResultAttribute o) {
        return o.Name == assignment.Name;
    })) != null)
        attribute.Value = assignment.Value;
    }
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 7):

The thing to do is to compile the method in a project C#, then have a look at the IL in the assembly it generates using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/). You can easily replicate that IL using Emit and make whatever dynamic changes you need.

Comment: Jonathan de Halleux has written a Reflection.Emit language add-in (http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=ReflectionEmitLanguage) for Reflector that makes this kind of thing even easier.  It's not quite perfect, but it'll generally get you about 95% of the way there, which is a heck of a lot better than starting with pure IL...

Answer (score 1):

c# create a closure (see wikipedia if you not familiar with) for you since in the anonymous method body you reference to the assignment variable (which is parameter in your case but this doesn't matter).

You need to create class holder for anonymous delegate (at least c# compiler does this)

then you need to create field in this class since your delegate closeover (i'm not native english so here maybe misspelling )
Assignment assignment parameter

Then in the body of AssignAttribute you should emit class instaniation
IL_0000:  newobj     instance void V24.Generated.Worker/'<>c__DisplayClass1'::.ctor()

as well as feild assignment
IL_0008:  stfld      class [nviss]NViss.Assignment V24.Generated.Worker/'<>c__DisplayClass1'::assignment

note that since filed initialization finished anywhere access to local variable was replaced with access to field

once again sorry for my English